# vue.js: Update data from watcher

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js, watch

I have the following code:

```
export default {
    name: '...',
    props: ['user'],
    data() {
        return {
            userName: this.user.name
        }
    },
    watch: {
        user: (_user) => {
            this.userName = _user.name
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...
    }
};
```

The userprop is updated by the parent component (it's information from the server). If I log the `_user` variable I have everything available. The `userName` prop doesn't update though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using fat arrow function as below:

```
user: (_user) => {
            this.userName = _user.name
        }
```

The **this** is not pointing to the vue instance, so by using   `this.userName` you are not refering to the   `userName` property in your data.

So use normal function like this:

```
user: function(_user){
            this.userName = _user.name
        }
```

There is a warning mentioned in vuejs docs regarding using an arrow function to define a watcher. You can have a look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)